# If a class is declared as final is it necessary to declare the methods as final

Tags: java, class, methods, final

I'm doing some reading and need some clarification on final classes and methods.  My understanding is that declaring a class as final prevents that class from being extended.  As such is it necessary to declare methods within a final class as final?  It seems to me that if the class cannot be extended it is not necessary to declare the methods final.

Comment: This seems only logical, however I was curious about this as well, since I couldn't find the answer in the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the class is declared as final, it is not necessary to declare the methods as final, because the class already cannot be extended.

Comment: Those were my thoughts exactly, thank you for the clarification!  Live Long and Prosper!

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark an answer as correct for the reference of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is implied, so it is not necessary (but you can do that anyway, if you feel like it).

Comment: Those were my thoughts exactly, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

`final` implies Class cannot be extended implies there is no scope for any method to be overloaded.. Thus it is redundant to have the final modifiers on the method..